# Highlighting intersection points of 2 functions (Mathematica)

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, intersection

Given two functions, I need to find their intersection points and show them on the graph. For this particular problem, the functions are: f(x) = - (x - 2) ^ 2, g(x) = x/(x+1).

So far, I have the following: 
   
 `Plot[{-(x - 2)^2 + 4, x/(x + 1)}, {x, 0, 4}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {White, LightBlue}}}]`
`NSolve[-(x - 2)^2 + 4 == x/(x + 1), {x, y}]`

But I have no idea how to show the points on a graph. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Epilog` option to add graphics primitives to a plot:

```
intersections = {x, y} /. 
   NSolve[y == -(x - 2)^2 + 4 && y == x/(x + 1), {x, y}];

Plot[{-(x - 2)^2 + 4, x/(x + 1)}, {x, 0, 4}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {White, LightBlue}}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[intersections]}]
```

[image]